# Dynamically Adding Web Control to .Aspx page with script blocks

Tags: c#, web-controls

I am trying to add a chart control to my .aspx page, but am getting the following error:

The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

with this code:

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  if (Context.Items.Contains("ajaxChart")) {
    ajaxChart = (bool) Context.Items["ajaxChart"];
  }

  if (Context.Items.Contains("chartControl") && ajaxChart) {
    _ChartControl = (ChartControl) Context.Items["chartControl"];
  }

  if (_ChartControl != null) {
    this.portletContent.Controls.Add(_ChartControl);
  }
}
```

The aspx page itself has two <%...%> block calling methods in my code behind.

`<body>
      <div id="portletContent" runat="server">
        <%=Render()%>
      </div>
    </body>`Has anyone solved this problem before? Is there another approach I can take to get around this. I basically need to inject this control into this page, and also run the Render() method inline at the right place

Answer (score 0):

Either replace the <%= with <%# (if you can) or add a PlaceHolder control into the page and add your control to the PlaceHolder's Control collection.